# Not all images showing in Reportviewer, or when printed. from a winforms project

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am using SQL Express 2012 Advanced and Visual Studio Pro 2012.

I have developed a report that displays signatures (stored in a database) on the report in reportviewer, one signature on each line. The report works fine as long as there aren't too many pages of data. Once the number of pages reaches around 100-200 pages, the images fail to load. You can see where this occurs if you watch the page count go up it counts very quickly by single numbers as it is rendering in the reportviewer then slows down and starts counting by jumps in numbers. If I lower the size of images saved in the database, I can get more images to load. So it seems to be a problem with the amount of memory the report is using.

Is there a cache setting for report viewer? Better yet, is there a way to know programmatically if the images are failing to load and to commit an action at that point?

Comment: Where are the images stored? What format? Resolution/dpi?

Comment: Images are stored in a SQL 2012 Express Db File Format is Compressed BMP. H 500 px X W 1500 px.

Comment: Those are rather large... Do you have the image object set to scale correctly? Many times it will drop the image if it can't place it when the scaling is not correct.

Comment: The image size on the rdlc is set to "Fit proportional". I have found that all images are loaded on the default rendering view they drop off when rendered in the Print Layout mode and if printed to the printer.

Comment: @user3059155  I am having the same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?